# How to change Iframe src value with onkeyup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I would like to make an embed helper for people.
So basically I would like to simular for [this](http://jsbin.com/kazarula/1/edit).
The problem with script is, that replce the original content, but not the src section.
For example:

```
<iframe src="INPUT_VALUE">
```

So the target is when you type an url for the input area,to appear in the textarea on iframe src.
[Here a image](http://i60.tinypic.com/2dwdy61.png) what  I whant

How to fix this?

Comment: This quetion is why so bad?
I mean, everybody know the answer for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend make a script for this, and I would like to share this!

```
<script>

 function setsrc(){
var src = document.getElementById("src_field").value;

document.getElementById("iframe_field").value = '<iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;" width="730"  height="569" src="'+src+'"></iframe>';
}

</script>
```

And the html part:

```
<p>Enter the URL:</p><br />
<input type="text" name="src_field" id="src_field" onKeyup="javascript: setsrc();   return false;"/>
<br /><br />
<p>Embed code:</p>
<br />
<textarea id="iframe_field">
<iframe allowfullscreen style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;" width="730"  height="569" src="" frameborder="0">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<iframe src="INPUT_VALUE">
```

jQuery code would be

```
$('element').keyup(function () {
   $('iframe').attr('src', 'new_source_link');
}
```

But note, iframe won't give you keyup event. Because it has no connection with your DOM. However, events can be handled on the site where it is actually hosted but not from an iframe.

Comment: Looks like this brake the script.